# Civilization 6 is stuck between turns

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

The city names no longer show, I can scroll but can't click on anything. I tried pressing every key to no avail. What's this...?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is some mods clashing with each other: CQUI got disabled because it was incompatible with GS and so I went and installed other mods doing similar things. Then a few days ago it got a new release and it got enabled and it crashed the game in this strange way. Manually disabling CQUI solved it -- I was able to reproduce it steadily by reloading but after disabling CQUI it never happened again.

This is confirmed on [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/comments/1125169247):

[image]